# How to smooth "internal" polygon borders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, generalization, smoothing

This is my first foray into GIS and GIS software. I am using ArcMap currently.

I have a shapefile of the world divided into different ecological regions. I would like to reduce the file size by generalizing/smoothing the edges of polygons inside the continent land masses. I want to perform these operations on edges that are adjacent to polygons for other ecological regions, but not on edges adjacent to oceans or waterways (no data).

Comment: If you're wanting to reduce file size I would suggest `Smooth` won't help with this - Smooth will add vertices to make a line look smoother - the opposite of Generalize which will remove vertices.

Comment: Probably you need a more general decomposition of these data than GIS can easily provide, but see if you can decompose to lines in a way that lets you isolate which to simplify, then recompose. It is certainly possible

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.